# Is there anything written by Newton's roommate Wilkins about him?

Tags: biographical-details, reference-request, newton

I've read that John Wilkins was Newton's room-mate and they lived together for 20 years. Is there anything about Newton written by Wilkins?

By the way, there is nothing easily found on google.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Part of the problem may be that Newton's roommate's name is spelled as Wickins or Wickens, not to be confused with bishop [John Wilkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Wilkins), Newton's older contemporary. Since they did live in the same room for 20 years Wickens's testimony would be precious indeed, but alas, as far as I know, the only things Wickens wrote concerning Newton were not about him but to him, letters. Some of the letters might be in the multi-volume [Correspondence of Isaac Newton by Cambridge University Press](https://www.cambridge.org/ec/academic/subjects/physics/history-philosophy-and-foundations-physics/correspondence-isaac-newton-volume-2?format=PB&isbn=9780521085991), but not it seems in the online [Newton’s Correspondence](http://www.newtonproject.ox.ac.uk/texts/correspondence/all). It would not help with the most common speculation concerning Wickens, however. According to [Waltz's history of autism](https://mnheritagesongbook.files.wordpress.com/2014/04/alicesevidenceapril2014revision.pdf):

> "*Others — e.g. Gribbin, p. 178* [Science: A History 1543-2001, BCA, 2002] *have suggested a homosexual relationship with his long-time roommate John Wickens, but there is no hint of this in their surviving correspondence.*"

[Spargo and Pounds in Newton's 'Derangement of the Intellect'](http://rsnr.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/34/1/11) quote a remark about Newton by Wickens's son Nicholas, but even that is just a reply to an inquiry forwarded to him by his father rather than some kind of memoir:

> "*He was turning Grey, I think, at Thirty, and when my Father observed y$^{\textrm{t}}$ to him as y$^{\textrm{e}}$ Effect of his deep attention of Mind, He would jest w$^{\textrm{th}}$ y$^{\textrm{e}}$ Experimy$^{\textrm{ts}}$ he made so often wth QuickSilver, as if from thence he took so soon that Colour.*"

The source is a manuscript labeled King's College Library, Cambridge, Keynes MS I37, not something that would be online either.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Nova](https://www.pbs.org/wgbh/nova/newton/principia.html):

> A more recent blow was the departure from Cambridge of John Wickens, Newtons room-mate for twenty years. Wickens became the minister of the parish church at Stoke Edith, married and fathered a son called Nicholas. Though they had through much together, the two friends would never meet again, and exchanged no more than a letter or two in the coming years.

Thus there is not likely to be much. Though see [this](https://www.heritage-history.com/index.php?c=read&author=gibson&book=scientists&story=more) for some anecdotal details.